# django testing load data using raw sql

Tags: django

I have a django project using multiple databases. I am using django-nose as the test runner. Test data is loaded to the default database using fixtures. I have a second database not managed by django models, where I want to create a structure and load some data before testing, using raw sql.

Is there any way to do this in a somehow clean way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ht Stathis,

Here was my scenario and how I solved it - YMMV..

1) I build up a [testrunner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner) and overriding the setup_databases method.  I needed to do this because I wanted to externally create this database.  We had custom tables, and functions.  I literally used the same code with one small deviation

```
class IManageTestRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    """This is a 3 line addition to the original method"""

    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

        ### Skipped for brevity ###

        for signature, (db_name, aliases) in dependency_ordered(test_databases.items(), dependencies):
            # Actually create the database for the first connection
            connection = connections[aliases[0]]
            old_names.append((connection, db_name, True))
            test_db_name = connection.creation.create_test_db(self.verbosity, autoclobber=not self.interactive)

            # Our little hack...
            if db_name == "bugs":
                create_IManage_instance(django_created_sql = True, mysql_db = "test_bugs",
                                    arg = value, arg2 = value )
            # End of our little hack..

            for alias in aliases[1:]:
                connection = connections[alias]

                ### Skipped for brevity ###
```

2) Add this to your settings.py
    `TEST_RUNNER = 'IManageTestRunner'`

3) Once this was created then I knew my test db was created.  I would then create tests which populated externally and test the results against it.

```
def test_add_property_value(self):
    """Test set / get a value"""
    # This will do some external process which occcurs to the db.
    pm = Pm(mysql_db='test_bugs', p4_port = settings.ICMSERVER_TEST_PORT)
    pmsite, pmproject, pmvariant, pmlibtype, pmlibrary, pmrelease = pm.add_release_tree()
    prop_type, pmvalue = ("string", "Funny Business")
    pmproperty = "%s_%s_basic" % (pmproject.name, prop_type)
    pm.add_property_definition(pmproperty, prop_type=prop_type)
    pm.add_propval(pmproperty, value=pmvalue, project=pmproject.name)

    # Now use Django to pull the value back out..
    project = Project.objects.get(name=pmproject.name)
    property = project.get_property(pmproperty)
    self.assertEqual(pmvalue, property.value)
```

Hope that helps took me awhile to figure it out.  I still have one issue (doing repeat inserts/queries..)